# Bootstrap flexible menubar according to devices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a menu bar in such a way that it should become a **Collapsible sidebar** on large screens and a normal **bootstrap menu bar** on small screens. I have seen [codeply demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/ppK9PJ4i5f) but its not interchangeable.

Also i want sidebar like [Altair](http://altair_app.tzdthemes.com/#/)
Please help !!
Thanx in advance

Comment: These sidebar examples may help: http://blog.codeply.com/2016/05/18/bootstrap-sidebar-responsive-examples/

Answer (score 1):

This solution by Jasny is not really a specific answer, but might help solve your problem: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu/

It will allow you to have a collapsible sidebar on Desktop/Laptop resolutions, but not the standard menu bar (stays as sidebar) in Tablet/Mobile viewports.

Play with the CSS/JS from the above demo and you should have a viable solution or at least a few hints as to how to reach your desired outcome.

Comment: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/ is another example that is pretty straightforward to customise to suit.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap Navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) is what you are talking about.

That is the basic component for such a feature. But to have similar neat feature such as you example (Altair) some additional modifications and plugins might be needed.

[Cody House](https://codyhouse.co) has some excellent examples there.

Other examples :

-[Bootsnip](http://bootsnipp.com/tags/navbar)

-[Tutorials](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-tutorial-navbar/)